# Save the value of the pressed button (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to save the value of the pressed button and its color, if the user clicks on the button, it will turn red when the user restarts the application, the color of the button will remain and be red, and the same with gray. I know that for something like this you need to use AppStorage or UserDefaults, but I haven't found how to use it in my case.

**Сode:**

```
struct HeartButtonView: View {
    @State private var isLiked = false
    var body: some View {
        HeartButton(isLiked: $isLiked)
    }
}


struct HeartButton: View {
    
    @Binding var isLiked: Bool
    @State private var animate = false
    private let animationDuration: Double = 0.1
    private var animationScale: CGFloat {
        isLiked ? 0.7 : 1.3
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            self.animate = true
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.animationDuration) {
                self.animate = false
                self.isLiked.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50)
                .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .red : .gray)
        }
        .scaleEffect(animate ? animationScale : 1)
        .animation(.easeIn(duration: animationDuration), value: animate)
        
    }
}
```

Thanks for any solution

Comment: You will need a model of some kind and some persistence. Look into CoreData or other forms of storage.

Comment: Why should I use CoreData? if I can store the value on the user's device

Comment: CoreDate without CloudKit is on the user's device. UserDefaults is for small insignificant values this is likely about more than a button, it is about the object that the user is "liking". You need to attach the "like" to the object itself not just create a variable that says liked.

Comment: Try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials, don't get caught up in the instant gratification that SwiftUI provides.

Comment: To store the values of the button, I use Fire Base if the user clicks on the button, the value increases by +1 like, but the value of the pressed button is not saved in red, I know that this is another question, just for visual display that the button is pressed

Comment: That is key, then replace my comments about CoreData to be about Firebase, use the object itself you don't need a second form of storage just use the variable from the model. Don't create 2 sources of truth.

Comment: I have an anonymous login to the application, I will not store the data of which user has put a like, I just need it for visual viewing

Comment: Try `AppStorage` instead of `State`

Comment: So I asked how do I use AppStorage in my example, you probably haven't read my question to the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `AppStorage` to store the state of this button, it's just a case of replacing

```
@State private var isLiked = false
```

with

```
@AppStorage("isLiked") private var isLiked = false
```

e.g

```
struct HeartButtonView: View {
    @AppStorage("isLiked") private var isLiked = false
    var body: some View {
        HeartButton(isLiked: $isLiked)
    }
}
```

The button state will be persisted between runs of the app